# Не могу подключиться по ssh из контейнера

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab

Не могу из контейнера приконнектиться к гитлабу.

```
FROM golang:1.15

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y git


ADD ./id_rsa /go/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN touch /go/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan git.***.ru >> /go/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN chmod 400 /go/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 400 /go/.ssh/
ADD ./.gitconfig /go/.gitconfig
RUN eval "$(ssh-agent)" && ssh-add /go/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ssh -T git@git.***.ru
RUN git clone https://user:password@git.***.ru/ap/database
```

На строке `RUN ssh -T git@git.***.ru` мне говорят:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

При этм, если я это делаю с хостовой тачки, всё ок.

Comment: https://github.com/go-training/golang-private-module/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина была в том, что стоит указывать `$HOME` вместо `$PWD`

Контейнер, который заработал:

```
FROM golang:1.15.5

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y git make

ARG CI_JOB_TOKEN
ARG CI_REGISTRY
ARG CI_JOB_USER

ADD ./id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T git@git.***.ru
```

Вывод:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'git.***.ru,1.2.3.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to GitLab, @user!
```